Is there a path integral expression for the Anomalous magnetic dipole moment?
I'm wondering how you might express the magnetic moment of the electron:
$$a_e = \frac{\alpha}{2\pi} + \mathcal{O}(\alpha^2) $$
In terms of a ratio of Feynman path integrals.e.g. something involving path integral like $\int F[\psi,\overline{\psi},A]e^{iS}D[\psi ,\overline{\psi}, A] / \int e^{iS}D[\psi ,\overline{\psi}, A] = \langle F\rangle$
(If we ignore such problems as renormalisation, convergence etc.) i.e. a non-perturbative formula. Probably involving a limit.
Edit: My latest attempt is below  (using this):
$$a_e  = \lim_{p\rightarrow 0}   \left\langle \frac{ \overline{u}(-p).\overline{\psi}(-p) \left( \int\epsilon_\mu(q).A(q)dq^4\right) \psi(p).u(p) - (p\leftrightarrow -p)}{\sigma^{\mu\nu} p_\nu} \right\rangle $$
Where $u(p)$ are solutions of $(\not p-m)u(p)=0$ and setting $\mu=1$ for example. Because the term involving $F_1(0)$ is an even function it can be got rid of by subtracting the same term with $p$ replaced by $-p$ I believe. The integral over q is to get rid of the delta function over the momentum. Instead of dividing by $p_\mu$ we instead take the derivative w.r.t. $p_\mu$ I think that would achieve the same thing.
From my reading, $a_e$ should be finite without renormalisation as the divergences appear in the form factor $F_1(0)$ not $F_2(0)$ but I'm not 100% certain on this. It also shouldn't depend on mass $m_e$, yet the calculations I've seen rely on having a non-zero mass which is cancelled at the end which is a bit weird.
I don't much like this formula as it is quite messy. Perhaps there is a nicer formula in the position space.
BTW. As a response to a comment, yes, physically the magnetic moment would also depend on other particles like muons and hadrons, but my interest is really on the mathematical side.
In position space I think it is, (maybe):
$$a_e \overset{?}{=} \int\int\langle \Box A_\mu(0) \not \partial \overline{\psi}(x) (x-y)_\nu\sigma^{\mu\nu} \not\partial \psi(y)\rangle dx^4 dy^4$$

@Ghoster Could you not work out such a formula using your QED knowledge?

No, because I learned QED before path integrals became popular.

Not sure how useful this comment is, but the anomalous magnetic moment comes from the loop corrections to the interaction vertex. The vertex, on the other hand, can be found by evaluating the three-point function that has a natural path integral representation $$\langle \bar \psi(x_1) \psi(x_2) A_\mu(x_3) \rangle = \int \mathfrak{D}\psi\mathfrak{D}\bar \psi \mathfrak{D}Ae^{iS[\psi,\bar\psi,A]} \bar \psi(x_1)\psi(x_2) A_\mu(x_3),$$ assuming a normalized measure. The question then is that one needs to decompose this 3pt function into form factors and extract one of them.

@Gold Exactly my thoughts. I think we need to take the limit as $x_1$, $x_2$ and $x_3$ approach each other and subtract off the form factors $F_1(0)$ that we don't want. The form factor $F_2(0)$ has a momentum term $q_\mu$ attached so we need to divide that out somehow to be left with just $F_2(0)$. But the exact details are beyond me. But I think it may be simpler in the momentum picture.

I feel like it may be proportional to: $a_e \propto \int \langle \overline{\psi}(q) \sigma^{\mu\nu} q_\mu A_\nu(0) \psi(-q)\rangle  dq^4$ but that might be of no use if the proportionality factor is unknown, possibly infinite.

Srednicki Ch. 64.  The (full) magnetic dipole moment corresponds to some electron-gauge vertex.  You can then say that it is the 1PI vertex function as defined by the Legendre-transformed free energy in the path integral language.  What good would that do, I don't know.  At the end of the day, all that functional integral sorcery doesn't help actual perturbative calculation.

@Vokaylop True but the perturbative calculation is an asymptotic series that begins to diverge after the 137th term. There are other ways to calculate path integrals than expanding them out in terms of the parameter $\alpha$

The 1PI vertex function has a non-perturbative definition based on path integral.  The expression is there.  You just have to figure out how to compute $-\ln Z$, in the presence of classical source, and Legendre transform it, all non-perturbatively...

It might be worth mentioning that for the anomalous magnetic moment, you would be interested in the prefactor for large-r (i.e. infrared) asymptotic decay of the field generated by an electron, not small-r (i.e. UV) behavior, which would ultimately depend on QCD (for UV completeness.) Hence, the renormalization group might be used to improve the accuracy of the calculation.
